# Compactness and finite (sub)covers

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, compactness

This is a question about possible alternative formulations of a compactness.

Suppose $R$ is an open set, and $S$ is a compact subset of $R$. Suppose we have an arbitrary open cover $R = \bigcup_{i\in I} T_i$. Then, as the cover of $R$ also covers $S$ can we, for each such cover construct a finite open cover of $R$ as follows, noting that as $R$ is open and $S$ is closed so $R \setminus S$ is open?

$$R = S \cup (R\setminus S) = \bigcup_{\text{finitely-many } i} T_i \cup (R \setminus S)$$

Ordinarily for compactness one specifies that this is a *sub*cover, so I'm inclined to say that this is not valid for showing that $R$ is in fact compact.

Shifting to the context of modules over a noetherian ring $A$ equipped with the weak topology, if more generally I have that $R$ and $S$ are both clopen $A$-modules with $S \subseteq R$, with $S$ compact, and that for some ideal $I$ of $A$ we have equality of quotients $R/IR = S/IS$. Then is it possible to show that $R$ is compact?

Thanks in advance,

M

Comment: What topology are you considering on $A$-modules? What's the relation between $R$ and $S$?

Comment: Any topology that makes them Hausdorff, and yes I should have specified the relation! Editing now :)

Comment: Two things: 1) Your edit doesn't clarify anything wrt. to what relation you assume between $R$ and $S$, and 2) "any topology that makes them Hausdorff" ok, take the discrete topology, then both are compact iff finite, qed. **Please specify a topology.**

Comment: The proof fails in that $R\setminus S$ is not known to be a member of the cover $\{T_i\}_{i\in I}$.

Comment: This is only a *sub*covering if $R\setminus S$ were contained in a finite number of the $T_i$.  This is akin to saying $(0,1)$ is compact as for any covering we combine all the sets that cover $(0,0.1)\cup (0.9,1)$ into one single set.

Comment: @Ben Steffan. I'm sorry about this. I've made a further edit to hopefully clarify my question.

Comment: @Chad K. That's precisely it -- my question was geared to asking whether we absolutely required that this be a member of the inital covering. I thought there might be some argument to be made since it was still a finite covering constructed from an arbitrary one. Thanks!

Comment: @mathieu_matheux: Yes, that's what 'subcover' means.  There are other notions like 'refinement' instead of 'subcover', but none of them allow to add a bulky new set of your own as a matter of convenience.

Comment: @fleadblood. Yep, we're on the same page there. The point of the question is that I was not assuming that we needed the set $[(0,0.1) \cup (0.9,1)]=T_k$ for some $k$ -- i.e. whether or not we could "construct" finitely-many open sets to adjoin to the overall cover from which a finite set was taken to cover the compact subset.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the first part of your question, you are correct in noting that this doesn't imply that $R$ is compact since proving compactness requires you to produce a finite *subcover* of a given cover. In fact, your proof would immediately show that all (non-empty) topological spaces are compact which is of course false :)